# Counting certain rows in a database & displaying only values greater than 0 of that one column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display some values from a database, and having some issues displaying the correct info.

In my database, there is a column called `coplevel` that column has enum values upto 7.

In my PHP side of things, I am trying to count all the user's in the database who have a `coplevel` > 0 but the thing's I have tried on SOF, work but not how I want it to work.

So if I have 5 user's with a cop level of 1,2,3,4,5 I want to count only the users who're coplevel is more than 0

```php
<?php
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `players` WHERE `coplevel` > 0";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $totalc = $row['0'];
            echo "<b>" . $totalc . "</b>";
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else {
        $totalc = "Couldn't find cop info";
    }
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
?>
```

If there is 5 user's who all have a `coplevel` over 0, then count and display only the ones who have > 0 as their `coplevel`

Comment: Your current count query already seems to be correct.  What is the problem with it, or what output do you want to see here?

Comment: So I just want it to display the amount of user's with a coplevel greater than 0, but it doesn't seem to do that. If i change my test account's coplevel to say.. 4 it changes the php posted above changes the value to 1 but if I change back the value to 0 the php posted above doesnt change the value back. So it still register's 1 member as having a coplevel higher than 0 when infact its set to 0 in the database. If that makes sense?

Comment: Please include sample data from the `players` table.  Something is going on which you are not articulating to us.

Comment: Not sure how to get some sample data, still new to this.. What data would you like?

Comment: Do you have any records that match that criteria?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct, but you are messing up with the `$row` array.

This:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

Will return the rows into an associative array called `$row`

An Associative array stores pairs of KEYS and VALUES

In this case, the key is the **column name** and the value is the **data** in the column.

You can access a value in the array either with its **index** in the array, or with its **key name**.

When you say :

```
$totalc = $row['0'];
```

You try to get the value of the array for which the key is named 0, but it doesn't exist

What you want to do, is getting the index 0. So you should say  :

```
$totalc = $row[0];
```

A clearer alternative is to alias properly your COUNT(*) in the query, in order to have a proper name for its key in your array :

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM `players` WHERE `coplevel` > 0";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $totalc = $row['cnt'];
```